# React - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

I am new to React and trying to build a react library with a basic utility using TS. I tried various ways by referring to different article but none worked for me. I always get same error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:26)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

***I have gone through all similar questions on stackoverflow but didnt work for me***

This is one of the article which I referred. I implemented this example with same step but still got the same error.

***https://prateeksurana.me/blog/react-library-with-typescript/***

Comment: What does the file that cannot be parsed contain? Which part of the error message is not clear? Which loaders do you have configured? Please provide more information.

Comment: If you don't tell us which kind of file has an issue, it's impossible to answer. Also, please post your webpack config.